# How to make common master page in BIRT reporting?

Tags: birt

How do I make a common masterpage in BIRT?  I'd like all of my reports to use a common master page, so that I can make a change in one place and all of the reports that use that master page automatically get the change.

Answer (score 8):

Create a masterpage in a BIRT library and then have all of your reports use that masterpage.  Here's how:

1. Open the BIRT report designer
2. File -> New -> New Library
3. In the Outline pane expand Masterpages.  Rename the masterpage to something meaningful - you'll want to do this in case you create multiple masterpages in the future.  For example, you may want one masterpage for Portait reports and a different one for Landscape reports.
4. Save
5. Open a report which you want to link to the common masterpage
6. In the Resource Explorer pane expand Shared Resources -> your newly created library -> MasterPages
7. Right click on your masterpage -> Add to Report
8. Delete the old masterpage in the report

Your report will then be linked to a common masterpage - if you change something in the masterpage, the report will automatically get that change.  You won't have to change the individual report.

Comment: Usually, the master page should contain some dynamic data, such as the title of the report.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to jrullmann's answer:

Usually, the masterpage should contain some dynamic data, such as the title of the report, and in some cases part of this data resides inside the DB.

To achieve this, you can for example create a Data Set "Masterpage" which resides in the same *.rptlibrary as the masterpage. 
The DS query has the form

```
select ? as title,
 ...
from DUAL
```

and has parameters like title, ... .

Bind the header and footer grid of the masterpage to this DS.

Then, in your report, reference the master page and change the DS parameter binding in the header and footer grid.